# No color effect on text

Tags: android

I want to send mail from my android application to given address. But now I am able send only plain text message. I want some text bold/underlines in different colors also. you can see my code below in which I used html form to bold text but I got mail with normal(plain) text means no effect of what should I do for this. Thanks.

```
String mailBody="<b style=\"color:#0066FF\">Jignesh</b>";

                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    String[] recipients = new String[] { "jansodariya@gmail.com" };
                    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,recipients);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Summ");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(mailBody));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: What email client are you viewing in? I know the default app on my Android device strips all colors, images, backgrounds, etc from the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<FONT COLOR=...> ... </FONT>` tag.

Comment: Hi Adil It works fine I can see color effect in my emulator but after sending the mail I got only plain text in mail. can you help me ?

Comment: Don't use `<font>` it's deprecated.